# Implementing a file format to be used with Encryption - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, encryption, aes, file-format, salt

I need to implement salts in my encryption, but to do so, I need to store it in a file format that I need to create so I can later retrieve it to decrypt. I'm a noob when it comes to encryption. The specifications of the file format should be as so:

Ciphertext: length of ciphertext ;
Salt: length of salt ;

Then the ciphertext and salt written out. This is where xcode really confuses me, as in creating a new file, etc.

How can I do this? And then retrieve the salt for decryption?

Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` like this:

```
// Example ciphertext and salt
NSString *ciphertext = @"the ciphertext";
NSString *salt = @"the salt";

// File destination
NSString *path = @"/Users/Anne/Desktop/Archive.dat";

// Create dictionary with ciphertext and salt
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:ciphertext forKey:@"ciphertext"];
[dictionary setObject:salt forKey:@"salt"];

// Archive dictionary and write to file
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
[data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

// Read file and unarchive
NSMutableDictionary *theDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

// Get ciphertext and salt
NSString *theCiphertext = [theDictionary objectForKey:@"ciphertext"];
NSString *theSalt = [theDictionary objectForKey:@"salt"];

// Show Result
NSLog(@"Extracted ciphertext: %@",theCiphertext);
NSLog(@"Extracted salt: %@",theSalt);
```

Output:

```
Extracted ciphertext: the ciphertext
Extracted salt: the salt
```

**EDIT**

Response to comment: Both `NSData` and `NSString` feature `length`.

Quick example:

```
NSString *theString = @"Example String";
NSData *theData = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger stringLength = [theString length];
NSUInteger dataLength = [theData length];

NSLog(@"String length: %ld",stringLength);
NSLog(@"Data length: %ld",dataLength);
```

Output:

```
String length: 14
Data length: 14
```

Comment: Wow! This is great, so this would serve as sort of bundling up the encryption into the file format and writing it to a file? And since the encrypted data is of type NSData, I would have to convert it as a string first to use this format?

Comment: Or can I just use type NSData like NSData *ciphertext =@"ciphertext". Probably a stupid question, but just clarifying

Comment: All classes conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol can be used by `NSKeyedArchiver`. Check for example the [NSData Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/) and notice `NSCoding` is mentioned under the "Conforms to" section. In conclusion, both `NSString` and `NSData` conform to the `NSCoding` protocol required by NSKeyedArchiver and can be used.

Comment: Indeed `NSKeyedArchiver` can be used to store virtually everything and is easy to implement.

Comment: Also, how can I get the length of both the salt and ciphertext?

Comment: Both `NSData` and `NSString` feature `length`. Added quick example above.

Comment: I was wondering, how was it possible to actually extract the salt and iv from the encrypted file without the lengths of the two pieces of data?